# Calling microservice from another C#

Tags: c#, service, middleware

I have 2 microservices:

- Tenant - Used to define which tenants exist on a system
- Identity - Used to register and authenticate users

Each request to `Identity` should contain a header of `TenantId` which will be used to register a user against a tenant within the Identity database. In order to do this each of the actions use the `[FromHeader]` to grab the tenant id like so:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromHeader] string tenantId, [FromBody] RegisterRequest request)
{
  // code here..
}
```

However before this action is called, the `tenantId` should be used to check if a tenant with that Id even exists.

I'm not sure which is the best way to do this, I have the following options in mind:

- Use middleware to grab the tenantId from the header and make a call
  to the `Tenant` service to check if one exists.
- Create an attribute and add to each action which would require a
  tenant check.

This brings another question to mind, should the tenant check happen before an action is executed or should it be done within the business layer?

Which would be the best option to use? If neither, can anyone suggest others?

Comment: I would use an attribute. The middleware will catch on every single call to the server, and it would be unnecessary to do so for calls that don't need this check.

You could also check inside the Register function

Comment: @GerritBergen When you say check inside the register function does that mean where the DI of services happen?

Comment: No, I mean in your API function. Like your code example, you have a Register function with your parameters. You could do the check in there. I would recommend an attribute though. That way you can easily reuse it in other functions.

Comment: @GerritBergen -.- my bad, brains not working today lol. But yeah, I like the idea of the attribute as then it can be reused and only used on actions with the attribute

Comment: All good :) Happy coding!